# HighCharts freezing when adding large number of Series

Tags: highcharts

Am trying to generate a scientific bubble chart and it is suppose to be presented as a dashboard. The chart is intended to reflect bubbles and these bubbles will be changing in size and location using an ajax call.

I was able to do must of that, but am facing a performance issue. The ajax is returning an average of 80 to 150 items each presented by a Series of type bubble.

As such, am faced with two problems

1) The browser freezes at every request, I tried to make the javascript sleep between each add operation but did not solve the problem.

2) After the first ajax call, other calls will need to alter existing Series of their facts has changes. How can I retrieve an existing Series and change its values in case it needs to be altered?

```
$(function () {

    function addPoint(chart){

        $.get("{{ main_site_url }}/dashboard/likelihood/ajax/",
            function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(k, dic) {
                    var newSeries = new Highcharts.Series();
                    newSeries.type = 'bubble';
                    newSeries.id = dic.id
                    newSeries.data = [[dic.id, dic.views, dic.likes] ];
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        chart.addSeries(newSeries);
                    }, 2000);

                });
            }, "jsonp"
        );
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bubble',
                zoomType: 'xy',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var chart = this;
                        setInterval(function() {
                            addPoint(chart)
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Likelihood bubbles'
            }

        });
    });

});
```

Comment: When you do this `chart.addSeries(newSeries);` each time you add a new serie your chart will redraw, change it to `chart.addSeries(newSeries, false);` and then after ends `$.each`, `chart.redraw();`.

Comment: have you tried to add all your bubbles as just one serie ? So you'd have one serie of 80~150 bubbles.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you use setTimeout(function() {
                        chart.addSeries(newSeries);
                    }, 2000); because when you get data, by $.get() all data is loaded. so what is purpose of refreshing and adding next series which has the same data?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I thought by using a sleep function I could draw objects into HighCharts without causing it to freeze